# AWS-EC2 - vsftpd: Failure retrieving contents of directory / - only on text editors

Tags: notepad++, ftp, amazon-ec2, vsftpd, webstorm

I got a very strange issue during the configuration of vsftpd on my ec2 instance:
I have configured the ftp server to use ftp over TLS and it worked fine on filezilla, however I didn't managed to connect using any text editors ftp module(I have tried with notepad++ and webstorm). I thought maybe the problem with the SSL, so I changed it first to simple unsecure FTP and try tto make it work. Now the FTP clients works like a charm again(filezilla, total commander), but the above text editors give me the following error after succefully connection:

```
Failure retrieving contents of directory /
```

I tried everything, but for now I have no clue what would be the issue. Here are my vsftp configurations:

```
listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=NO
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=ftp
ssl_enable=NO
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=1024
pasv_max_port=1048
port_enable=YES
pasv_address=[EC2_PUBLIC_DOMAIN]
pasv_addr_resolve=YES
```

Does anyone has any idea what should be the problem? Every help are welcome. Thanks.

**UPDATE** (server side logs)

Filezilla:

```
Sat Jan 14 20:01:06 2017 [pid 8099] CONNECT: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229"
Sat Jan 14 20:01:06 2017 [pid 8099] FTP response: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229", "220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)"
Sat Jan 14 20:01:06 2017 [pid 8099] FTP command: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229", "AUTH TLS"
Sat Jan 14 20:01:06 2017 [pid 8099] FTP response: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229", "530 Please login with USER and PASS."
Sat Jan 14 20:01:06 2017 [pid 8099] FTP command: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229", "AUTH SSL"
Sat Jan 14 20:01:06 2017 [pid 8099] FTP response: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229", "530 Please login with USER and PASS."
Sat Jan 14 20:01:06 2017 [pid 8099] FTP command: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229", "USER dev_back"
Sat Jan 14 20:01:06 2017 [pid 8099] [dev_back] FTP response: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229", "331 Please specify the password."
Sat Jan 14 20:01:06 2017 [pid 8099] [dev_back] FTP command: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229", "PASS <password>"
Sat Jan 14 20:01:06 2017 [pid 8098] [dev_back] OK LOGIN: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229"
Sat Jan 14 20:01:06 2017 [pid 8100] [dev_back] FTP response: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229", "230 Login successful."
Sat Jan 14 20:01:06 2017 [pid 8100] [dev_back] FTP command: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229", "PWD"
Sat Jan 14 20:01:06 2017 [pid 8100] [dev_back] FTP response: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229", "257 "/" is the current directory"
```

Notepad++:

```
Sat Jan 14 20:01:37 2017 [pid 8102] CONNECT: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229"
Sat Jan 14 20:01:37 2017 [pid 8102] FTP response: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229", "220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)"
Sat Jan 14 20:01:37 2017 [pid 8102] FTP command: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229", "USER dev_back"
Sat Jan 14 20:01:37 2017 [pid 8102] [dev_back] FTP response: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229", "331 Please specify the password."
Sat Jan 14 20:01:37 2017 [pid 8102] [dev_back] FTP command: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229", "PASS <password>"
Sat Jan 14 20:01:37 2017 [pid 8101] [dev_back] OK LOGIN: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229"
Sat Jan 14 20:01:37 2017 [pid 8103] [dev_back] FTP response: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229", "230 Login successful."
Sat Jan 14 20:01:37 2017 [pid 8103] [dev_back] FTP command: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229", "TYPE A"
Sat Jan 14 20:01:37 2017 [pid 8103] [dev_back] FTP response: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229", "200 Switching to ASCII mode."
Sat Jan 14 20:01:37 2017 [pid 8103] [dev_back] FTP command: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229", "MODE S"
Sat Jan 14 20:01:37 2017 [pid 8103] [dev_back] FTP response: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229", "200 Mode set to S."
Sat Jan 14 20:01:37 2017 [pid 8103] [dev_back] FTP command: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229", "STRU F"
Sat Jan 14 20:01:37 2017 [pid 8103] [dev_back] FTP response: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229", "200 Structure set to F."
Sat Jan 14 20:01:38 2017 [pid 8103] [dev_back] FTP command: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229", "PWD"
Sat Jan 14 20:01:38 2017 [pid 8103] [dev_back] FTP response: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229", "257 "/" is the current directory"
Sat Jan 14 20:01:38 2017 [pid 8103] [dev_back] FTP command: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229", "CWD /"
Sat Jan 14 20:01:38 2017 [pid 8103] [dev_back] FTP response: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229", "250 Directory successfully changed."
Sat Jan 14 20:01:38 2017 [pid 8103] [dev_back] FTP command: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229", "PASV"
Sat Jan 14 20:01:38 2017 [pid 8103] [dev_back] FTP response: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229", "227 Entering Passive Mode (0,0,0,0,4,2)."
Sat Jan 14 20:01:38 2017 [pid 8103] [dev_back] FTP command: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229", "LIST"
Sat Jan 14 20:02:38 2017 [pid 8103] [dev_back] FTP response: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229", "425 Failed to establish connection."
```

Filezilla own log:

```
2017-01-14 21:27:41 4856 1 Response: 220 (vsFTPd 3.0.3)
2017-01-14 21:27:41 4856 1 Command: AUTH TLS
2017-01-14 21:27:41 4856 1 Response: 530 Please login with USER and PASS.
2017-01-14 21:27:41 4856 1 Command: AUTH SSL
2017-01-14 21:27:41 4856 1 Response: 530 Please login with USER and PASS.
2017-01-14 21:27:41 4856 1 Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
2017-01-14 21:27:41 4856 1 Command: USER dev_back
2017-01-14 21:27:41 4856 1 Response: 331 Please specify the password.
2017-01-14 21:27:41 4856 1 Command: PASS ***********
2017-01-14 21:27:42 4856 1 Response: 230 Login successful.
2017-01-14 21:27:42 4856 1 Command: SYST
2017-01-14 21:27:42 4856 1 Response: 215 UNIX Type: L8
2017-01-14 21:27:42 4856 1 Command: FEAT
2017-01-14 21:27:42 4856 1 Response: 211-Features:
2017-01-14 21:27:42 4856 1 Response:  EPRT
2017-01-14 21:27:42 4856 1 Response:  EPSV
2017-01-14 21:27:42 4856 1 Response:  MDTM
2017-01-14 21:27:42 4856 1 Response:  PASV
2017-01-14 21:27:42 4856 1 Response:  REST STREAM
2017-01-14 21:27:42 4856 1 Response:  SIZE
2017-01-14 21:27:42 4856 1 Response:  TVFS
2017-01-14 21:27:42 4856 1 Response: 211 End
2017-01-14 21:27:42 4856 1 Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
2017-01-14 21:27:42 4856 1 Status: Logged in
2017-01-14 21:27:42 4856 1 Status: Retrieving directory listing...
2017-01-14 21:27:42 4856 1 Command: PWD
2017-01-14 21:27:42 4856 1 Response: 257 "/" is the current directory
2017-01-14 21:27:42 4856 1 Command: TYPE I
2017-01-14 21:27:42 4856 1 Response: 200 Switching to Binary mode.
2017-01-14 21:27:42 4856 1 Command: PASV
2017-01-14 21:27:42 4856 1 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (0,0,0,0,4,12).
2017-01-14 21:27:42 4856 1 Status: Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.
2017-01-14 21:27:42 4856 1 Command: LIST
2017-01-14 21:27:42 4856 1 Response: 150 Here comes the directory listing.
2017-01-14 21:27:42 4856 1 Response: 226 Directory send OK.
2017-01-14 21:27:42 4856 1 Status: Directory listing of "/" successful
```

Comment: Check what mode (active/passive) are FileZilla and the editors using - If you cannot tell, show us a verbose log from FileZilla and the editors. If the editors cannot create a log, show us a server-side log. Or FTP protocol capture (e.g. using Wireshark).

Comment: I updated with the server side logs. Both should use passive mode. I double checked the filezilla settings and the passive mode was set, but I don't see it in the logs...

Comment: Please post FileZilla log that shows directory listing (that's what fails in Notepad++).

Answer (score 1):

> Sat Jan 14 20:01:38 2017 [pid 8103] [dev_back] FTP response: Client "::ffff:178.48.165.229", "227 Entering Passive Mode (**0,0,0,0**,4,2)."

This looks like a bug of vsftpd FTP server, when the public `pasv_address` is set, and the server has a (local) IPv6 address (what is the case of EC2).

I've posted more about the bug on Server Fault question [Vsftpd passive reply with 0,0,0,0 address even with correct pasv_address](https://serverfault.com/q/821025/168875).

---

FileZilla can ignore the invalid IP address:

> 2017-01-14 21:27:42 4856 1 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (0,0,0,0,4,12).
>   2017-01-14 21:27:42 4856 1 Status: Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.

But Notepad++ cannot.